# pip not installed with python and it wont install itself

Tags: python, pip

after running into problems with package installment using anaconda i decided to just create a new Virtual Machine to work on, so i made a new one (win 8) and installed the latest python and sublime text. now when i type "pip" in CMD i get an error and when i tried installing it from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py nothing installed!

i've tried reinstalling python and  changing cds in CMD

all i want to do is be able to install libraries for my programs

from cmd : 
C:\Users\stupid python v2>'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
and 
C:\Users>'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: That should mean the pip program is not inside the environment PATH variable

Comment: then what should i do to get it there

Comment: Try to press look for the ''edit environment variables'' option in windows, usually is by pressing the Win button and typing something like ''change environment variable'' or ''environment variables'', once you found out the option a window will appear and it will let you change your user variables or the system variables. I recommend you to change your user's variable Path, and inside of it type the file path where the program is

Comment: i did and it still didnt work

Comment: I will let you this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/502358/easier-way-to-change-environment-variables-in-windows-8) of how to do it in case you did wrong because of my bad english but it should work, the other thing you could do if trying to reinstall it step by step again and make sure that your program enters in the PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip is usually in your python > scripts folder.

Try: `path/to/python/scripts> pip install my_package`